# Using trigger how to update varchar(including number) column sequentially.....?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, oracle

I have one contact table like

Contact_ID   Name     MMS_Contact_ID

```
   1         A         MMSC000001
```

When am inserting 2nd record (2,B) After update the Third column like (MMSC000002)
 third column datatype(Varchar)....

write a trigger in this table.....

In MMS_Contact_ID (MMSC is Constant) when am reaching the 999999 show the error....

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the `MMS_Contact_ID` with the value of `Contact_ID`, you can do it like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER updcol BEFORE INSERT ON tablename
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SET NEW.MMS_Contact_ID = 'MMSC' + LPAD(convert(varchar, NEW.Contact_ID), 6, '0');
  END;
```